# Extremely strange behavior in Internet Explorer with large GWT app

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, gwt-rpc

I have a loader on my page which is removed once I receive a successful response to my RPC.  If the RPC call fails, the page is instantly refreshed.

Anytime I load my page for the first time in IE 7 or 8, it will never load AND never reach the rpc call has failed method.  Every time I manually refresh that failed load, it works.  I've been able to reproduce this about 30 times.  This is a problem because the page just sits there with a loader on the screen.

I have no idea what could be happening.  Try it out for yourself:

1) Open up IE7 or IE8.
2) Go to http://www.foodtrucksmap.com/
3) The page will say done and sit there with a loader on the screen forever.
4) Refresh the page and it should work.

I've only been able to come up with one bad solution... create a timer for 30 seconds and if the loader is still on the screen, refresh the page.  I'd rather discover whats happening though.

**UPDATE**

As a second temporary solution, I'm going to add a cookie that expires immediately and reload if its ie accessing for the first time in the session.

Comment: You have to explain some technical details about how are you displaying/hiding the loader when the rpc responce arrives. Do you use eventHandler?

Comment: It's the entry point for my app.  onModuleLoad, i call getMyObjects() which has a callback of service_eventListTrucksFailed or service_eventListTrucksSucceded.  I remove the logo on succeeded, and refresh the page on failed.  Neither are getting called back

Comment: I could not reach your url. Connection is timing out. I think, there is any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've had nasty experiences with IE caching AJAX GET requests, no matter what we tried.
Where it mattered, the best solution we could find was to use POST, which solved the problem, but is a work-around. Changing headers to explicitly disallow caching did not work too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what limited information you have posted and what I was able to pull out of your site I am wondering if you are hitting a request timout or other server related issue. For instance you have 36 un-compressed javascript files loading (35 of which completing) and a whole host of 407 proxy errors.

You have to be amazingly careful with your load order of js files and where you place your script tags. IE is especially sensitive about this.

You have two options:

1. Try adding defer to your script tags; this should force it to load the js after the content is loaded.
2. As yahoo suggests move the script tags to just above your closing body tag () and then try it to see if it makes a difference.  I bet that it is waiting to load the content based on the javascript files have not finished loading and the whole thing times out.